# Search Field, clear default text on focus - FF 3.6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox3.6

I've tried the jQuery and JavaScript solutions here:

[How to clear text field on focus of text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324159/how-to-clear-text-field-on-focus-of-text-field)

All of which work, but not on FF 3.6 for some odd reason. *SO!* **What can I use for this feature to work on FF 3.6 / that generation older browsers?**

I'd like the search field to display my styled default text, and when the user clicks inside the field, the text would disappear, and when clicked back out - it should reappear again. Just as they all do nowadays.

*Thanks for any help*

***Update:*** Have just tried this JS; and it rendered there at first in 3.6, but after clicking in field and out it never came back. Also, after refreshing, and even clearing cache it hadn't came back again??

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Clear Form Demo</title>

<script language="javascript">
<!--
function ClearForm() {
  document.testform.email.value= "";
}

//-->
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="testform">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="Something here." onfocus="ClearForm();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not try making a super simple HTML page with jQuery JS that demonstrates the exact issue (should be around 15-20 lines total). Also, check your FF error console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have said `HTML5` placeholder attribute immediately, but that isn't supported in Firefox 3.6 as well. [Here](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html) is a fix using `jQuery` for all other browsers. You can try it out.

Comment: I'm here because of the non-supporting HTML5 placeholder which I currently had implemented!!

Comment: Yeah, try the above fix. It really worked for when I was facing the same issue.

Comment: That link you suggested looks awesome. Though I think it may not work in FF 3.6, as I'm currently browsing 3.6 and their demos aren't working??

Comment: I would still say, give it a try :)